# What is this servo to Pi connector?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, servo

I'm trying to connect [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CFUBN8) servo to my RPi3 with as little wire as possible. What is this red, black, green wire called that allows me to connect a servo to my Pi? 
[image]

Comment: they are called jumper wires. From the pictures I can't tell the gender, but these come with male and female ends.

Comment: You need some male to female jumper wires.  The female end will plug into the Pi's male pins.  The male end will plug into the female servo plug.

Comment: @joan If it's male female jumper wires, why do I need any in the first place? can it just plug right into the GPIO?

Comment: No, because you need adjacent expansion header pins which are ground, then 5V, then a GPIO.  There are no such pins.

Comment: @joan I'm sorry for my lack of understanding, but to clarify, a jumper cable has the adjacent expansion header pins and 5V in it? So all I would need to connect a RPi3 to this servo is just 3 male female jumper cables?

Comment: You need three separate single wire jumper wires.  You can then plug them in as needed (as in the photo in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Buying [jumper wires](https://www.adafruit.com/categories/306) premade would do the job. If you *really* want to make them yourself you need some [hookup wire](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1311) and some [dupont/rectangular connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/what-are-those-wire-terminals-that-mate-with-standard-header-pins). There's a [crimp tool](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dupont-Crimping-Crimper-2-54mm-0-1-1-0m2/dp/B00EEWRWX8) that goes with them, but generally I just use a dab of solder and some fine pliers to close the crimp. They're *finicky* though - a millimetre out of place into the metal part with the solder and it won't fit into the plastic housing.

Comment: Look at where the jumper cables meet the servo cables, do I need to buy that black thing or is that just something to keep the wires together? And do I need the jumper wires at all? Could it just plug straight into the GPIO?

Comment: The 'black thing' is just the connectors on the ends of the wires plugged into each other. Take a look at some [dupont connectors](http://www.dx.com/p/1-pin-dupont-wire-connector-cables-40-pcs-20cm-151537#.WH_0h1yND1w). The servo will come with a connector attached to its cable. You'll need to run your own male to female jumper wires from that connector to a GPIO pin, 5V and GND.